# Run .exe file inside .asm file

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm

x86 Assembly.

I have .asm file and I wanna to run another .exe program in the my .asm file code.
How to do that?

Comment: Which OS and assembler?

Comment: I use DOSbox, TASM and TLINK.

Comment: Then I suggest you read Kip Irvine's ["Loading and executing a child process"](http://kipirvine.com/asm/articles/ExecChild.pdf), as well as the [`int 21h / ah=4Bh` documentation](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2939.htm).

Comment: I miss some instructions inside of these examples for to save SS and SP before calling the interrupt for executing a child. And if we want to get the command tail from a PSP of a child, then we have to exept that the current PSP is not necessarily the caller's PSP and so we have to get the current PSP address before: AH=62h int 21h return BX = segment of PSP for current process. And for to execute a batch file we can use DS:SI -> commandline to execute with int 2Eh. Allows execution of arbitrary commands (including COMMAND.COM internal commands) without loading another copy of COMMAND.COM.